# Is there a package manager for Linux that is similar to Homebrew for Mac?

Tags: linux, package-management

Is there a package manager for Linux that is similar to Homebrew for Mac?

I know a tool named `yum`, but this tool's dependency package is not the latest version. Some code does not work.

Comment: I think **you're asking the wrong question**. Why not elaborate on what doen't work with `yum`? "Some code does not work"? In all Linux distributions, there's already a package manager, and everyone uses it. What problem do you have?

Comment: i just want to use package manager in linux which like homebrew for mac !

Comment: What do you mean by "Some code does not work"? Are you looking for a tool that automates building from source rather than what the typical package managers provide?

Comment: so that means the verssion too old my code need new verssion

Comment: **Which code** of yours requires **which version** of **what**?

Comment: some likes imagemagick my code need 6.7.X but yum just verssion at 6.2.X so that my code not work !

Comment: You're looking for source-based package management then? I don't believe there are alternative package managers, since they would interfere with the distribution itself. However there are other distributions that install from source only. Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Sourcecode-based_installation_.2F_Installing_using_compile_scripts) helpful?

Comment: There is Homebrew for Linux: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on which distribution you are using, if it is Debian based (Ubuntu, etc) then apt is the standard. If you use a redhat based distro (CentOS, Fedora) then you would normally use yum. There are others too. Do some research. A quick google returned this result which looks quite helpful: http://library.linode.com/using-linux/package-management

Answer (score -2):

The de facto standard is [apt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)

Comment: don't like apt i prefer yum

Comment: yum, yast, pacman, apt, theres so many